# Using postgresql fuzzy operator on inlined array

Tags: postgresql

I would like to leverage postgresql fuzzy matching on data that does not come from tables, the final goal being to try to match country names with typos. I've tried this :

```
select foo from (select ARRAY['France', 'Thailand', 'Germany' ]) as foo where 'Thailande' % any(foo);
```

Which produces error :

```
ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

Trying to typecast `foo` seems to imply the result for my sub select statement is not considered as type array but record instead :

```
=> select foo from (select ARRAY['France', 'Thailand', 'Germany' ]) as foo where 'Thailande' % any(foo::varchar[]);
ERROR:  cannot cast type record to character varying[]
LINE 1: ...', 'Germany' ]) as foo where 'Thailande' % any(foo::varchar[...
                                                             ^
```

Is there any mean to force array type or to accomplish the desired result an other way ?

Note : I'm using postgresql-9.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the salient point here is that `foo` does not designates a field but a row.

Possibly you want this:

```
select foo from (select ARRAY['France', 'Thailand', 'Germany' ]) as a(foo)
  where 'Thailande' % any(a.foo);
```

Note however that this will select the entire array as a result, not the individual component that matches `Thailande`.

To get the individual word, I'd rather not use an array in the first place but a `VALUES` clause instead , as in:

```
select foo from (values ('France'), ('Thailand'), ('Germany')) 
 as a(foo)
where 'Thailande' % a.foo;
```

Result:

```
   foo    
----------
 Thailand
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Hi, 

for reference, I came across this alternative syntax (doesn't add anything, but worth mentioning) :

`select foo from unnest( ARRAY['France', 'Thailand', 'Germany'] ) as foo where 'Thailand' = foo;`

Comment: (as far as I understand, it actually converts array to rows, so it's the same as writing a list of values, if not a bit less efficient due to doing a translation, but I love the syntax)